# Sql error 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i am trying to execute the following sql query

```
select * 
from TURMAS t
where exists (select * 
                from (
                     select count(*) Alunos 
                        from HISTORICOS h1 
                        where h1.ANO = t.ANO
                        and h1.SEMESTRE = t.SEMESTRE 
                        and h1.COD_DISC = t.COD_DISC
                      ) a ,
                     (
                     select count(*) Reprovados
                        from HISTORICOS h2 
                        where h2.SITUACAO <> 'AP' 
                        and h2.ANO = t.ANO 
                        and h2.SEMESTRE = t.SEMESTRE
                        and h2.COD_DISC = t.COD_DISC
                      ) r
                 where ((r.REPROVADOS * 100) / a.ALUNOS) >= 60
                );
```

but every time i try to execute it i get (00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier") on line 24 (or any other line i try to use the alias of TURMAS, even when i try to use the TURMAS w/o alias.

i could not find the error in the query.

here is the describe TURMAS

```
SQL> describe turmas
 Nome                                      Nulo?    Tipo
 ----------------------------------------- -------- -------------------------
 ANO                                       NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 SEMESTRE                                  NOT NULL NUMBER(1)
 COD_DISC                                  NOT NULL NUMBER(6)
 VAGAS                                     NOT NULL NUMBER(3)
 IDT_PROF                                           NUMBER(6)
```

SQL describe HISTORICOS

```
SQL> describe historicos
 Nome                                      Nulo?    Tipo
 ----------------------------------------- -------- -------------------------
 ANO                                       NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 SEMESTRE                                  NOT NULL NUMBER(1)
 MAT_ALU                                   NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
 COD_DISC                                  NOT NULL NUMBER(6)
 SITUACAO                                  NOT NULL CHAR(2)
 MEDIA                                     NOT NULL NUMBER(3,1)
 FALTAS                                    NOT NULL NUMBER(3)
```

and a select * from V$VERSION

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM V$VERSION;

BANNER
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.2.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
```

I got the same error both on Oracle SQL Developer and Dbeaver, when i try to to the same thing but intead of using t.**** an constant, it works.

Comment: I didn't think you could nest a reference to a corralled table more than 1 level deep.  [askTom's article on it](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1853075500346799932)  Salient line: **and we said...

ANSI SQL has table references (correlation names) scoped to just one level deep**

Comment: even using

    select * 
 from TURMAS aliasOfTurma, 
  (select * 
   from HISTORICOS aliasOfHistorico
   where aliasOfHistorico.ANO=aliasOfTurma.ANO);

just to test, it gives the same error.

Comment: I feel very strongly that this should be a JOIN, not a WHERE EXISTS with a correlated subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to xQbert link it worked. i didnt even thought about deepness?, ugly, probl with a poor performance but it works now, since it have to be delivered in 2 hours and is for college not a work query, it will do.

```
select * 
from TURMAS t
where (
      select count(*) Alunos 
            from HISTORICOS h1 
            where h1.ANO = t.ANO
            and h1.SEMESTRE = t.SEMESTRE 
            and h1.COD_DISC = t.COD_DISC
      ) > 0
and(
        select count(*) * 0.6 Alunos 
            from HISTORICOS h1 
            where h1.ANO = t.ANO
            and h1.SEMESTRE = t.SEMESTRE 
            and h1.COD_DISC = t.COD_DISC
      ) <= (
         select count(*) Reprovados
            from HISTORICOS h2 
            where h2.SITUACAO <> 'AP' 
            and h2.ANO = t.ANO 
            and h2.SEMESTRE = t.SEMESTRE
```

xQbert

> I didn't think you could nest a reference to a corralled table more than 1
>       level deep. askTom's article on it Salient line: and we said... ANSI SQL has
>       table references (correlation names) scoped to just one level deep